# my comparing of strings in python not working

Tags: python, string, compare

I am beginner and I am writing a simple Python program of converting RNA sequence to protein codons. So I have an RNA string and I take every 3 letters (such as UUU) and convert it to a protein codon that it is associated with. So "UUU" converts to "F", "UUA" converts to "L" and so on. Here is my code:

```
my_rna="UUAUUGUUUUUC"
my_protein=""
for i in xrange(0,len(my_rna),3):
    sub_str = my_rna[i:(i+3)]
    print sub_str
    if sub_str=="UUU" or "UUC":
        my_protein +="F"
    elif sub_str=="UUA" or "UUG":
        my_protein +="L"
    else:
        print "No match"
    print i

print my_protein
```

this is the output:

```
UUA
0
UUG
3
UUU
6
UUC
9
FFFF
```

So the problem seems to be that every substring of the 3 RNA letters seems to be true for the first IF statement and so all the RNA 3 letter sets translate to "F" even though the output should be "AAFF"?

Could someone tell me why this is and how can I fix it? I read around and there is a difference between using `==` and `is` when comparing strings in Python because they mean different things in the condition, however I don't think this is the problem because when I tried replacing my `==` with `is`, the same output happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The

```
if sub_str=="UUU" or "UUC":
```

should be written as

```
if sub_str=="UUU" or sub_str=="UUC":
```

or

```
if sub_str in ("UUU", "UUC"):
```

In the latter, the parentheses can be replaced with square brackets or curly braces. Since there's no practical difference in your case, I won't go into that further.

What you have right now is valid syntactically but doesn't do what you expect it to do. It is equivalent to:

```
if (sub_str=="UUU") or bool("UUC"):
```

and always evaluates to `True` (since `bool("UUC")` is `True`).

(All of this applies to the `elif` comparison too.)

Comment: `in ("UUU", "uuc",)` is very preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
if sub_str=="UUU" or "UUC":
    ...
```

A common mistake many beginners make is to assume this means 'proceed if sub_str is equal to EITHER "UUU" OR "UUC"'. In reality, this actually means 'proceed if sub_str is equal to "UUU" OR if "UUC" evaluates to a truthy value".

Since "UUC" is treated as 'True', your first 'if' statement always executes.

You can fix this by either doing:

```
if sub_str == "UUU" or sub_str == "UUC":
```

...or by doing:

```
if sub_str in ("UUU", "UUC"):
```

...which is a nice shortcut.